# filter file by unique and biggest value; combine two arrays into hash

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I need to extract by unique genus (first part of the name of species) in one column but with by biggest number in another column in a CSV file when having multiples of the same name.

So if have multiple genus (same first name) then take the biggest number in the last column to select which will represent that genus.

I have extracted the information into arrays, but I am having trouble with combining the two in order to select.  I was using 
https://perlmaven.com/unique-values-in-an-array-in-perl 
to help but I need to include biggest number in last column when have the same genus situation.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open taxa_fh, '<', "$ARGV[0]" or die qq{Failed to open "$ARGV[0]" for input: $!\n};

open match_fh, ">$ARGV[0]_genusLongestLEN.csv" or die qq{Failed to open for output: $!\n};my @unique;

my %seen;
my %hash;

while ( my $line = <taxa_fh> ) {
   chomp( $line );
   my @parts = split( /,/, $line );
   my @name = split( / /, $parts[3]);
   my @A = $name[0];
   my @B = $parts[5];
   @seen{@A} = ();
   my @merged = (@A, grep{!exists $seen{$_}} @B);
   my @merged = (@A, @B);
   @hash{@A} = @B;
   print "$line\n";
}

close taxa_fh;
close match_fh;
```

## Input example:

```
AB179735.1.1711,AB179735.1.1711,278983,Eucyrtidium hexagonatum,0,1600
AB179736.1.1725,AB179736.1.1725,278986,Pterocorys zancleus,0,1763
AB181888.1.1758,AB181888.1.1758,281609,Protoperidinium crassipes,0,1700
AB181890.1.1709,AB181890.1.1709,281610,Protoperidinium denticulatum,0,1800
AB181892.1.1738,AB181892.1.1738,281611,Protoperidinium divergens,0,1800
AB181894.1.1744,AB181894.1.1744,281612,Protoperidinium leonis,0,1500
AB181899.1.1746,AB181899.1.1746,281613,Protoperidinium pallidum,0,1600
AB181902.1.1741,AB181902.1.1741,261845,Protoperidinium pellucidum,0,1750
AB181904.1.1734,AB181904.1.1734,281614,Protoperidinium punctulatum,0,1599
AB181907.1.1687,AB181907.1.1687,281615,Protoperidinium thorianum,0,1600
AB120001.1.1725,AB120001.1.1725,244960,Gyrodinium spirale,0,1500
AB120002.1.1725,AB120002.1.1725,244961,Gyrodinium fusiforme,0,1800
AB120003.1.1724,AB120003.1.1724,244962,Gyrodinium rubrum,0,1700
AB120004.1.1723,AB120004.1.1723,244963,Gyrodinium helveticum,0,1500
AB120309.1.1800,AB120309.1.1800,4442,Camellia sinensis,0,1700
```

## Wanted output:

```
AB179735.1.1711,AB179735.1.1711,278983,Eucyrtidium hexagonatum,0,1600
AB179736.1.1725,AB179736.1.1725,278986,Pterocorys zancleus,0,1763
AB181890.1.1709,AB181890.1.1709,281610,Protoperidinium denticulatum,0,1800
AB120002.1.1725,AB120002.1.1725,244961,Gyrodinium fusiforme,0,1800
AB120309.1.1800,AB120309.1.1800,4442,Camellia sinensis,0,1700
```

Comment: Why is *Protoperidinium denticulatum* selected and not *Protoperidinium divergens*? They both have 1800 in the last column.

Comment: I only need one to represent that genus. So if I have the same number then I just pick at random between the two or more.

Comment: Are the species of the same genus always adjacent?

Comment: No, not always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properly naming the variables makes the code more readable:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %selected;
while (<>) {
    my ($species, $value) = (split /,/)[3, 5];
    my $genus = (split ' ', $species)[0];
    if ($value > ($selected{$genus}{max} || 0)) {
        $selected{$genus}{max} = $value;
        $selected{$genus}{line} = $_;
    }
}
for my $genus (keys %selected) {
    print $selected{$genus}{line};
}
```

The order of the output lines is random.

Comment: This assumes the last field will always be non-negative. (Probably ok, but you should have mentioned it!)

Comment: This only handles a subset of CSV.

Comment: Yes, the danger of guessing the spec from a sample input.

Answer (score 1):

```
use Text::CSV_XS qw( );

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({
   auto_diag   => 2,
   binary      => 1,
   quote_space => 0,
});

my %by_genus;
while ( my $row = $csv->getline(\*ARGV) ) {
   my ($genus) = split(' ', $row->[3]);
   $by_genus{$genus} = $row
      if !$by_genus{$genus}
      || $row->[5] > $by_genus{$genus}[5];
}

$csv->say(select(), $_) for values(%by_genus);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can this Perl command line as well

```
perl -F, -lane ' ($g=$F[3])=~s/(^\S+).*/$1/; if( $mx{$g}<$F[-1]) 
   { $kv{$g}=$_;$mx{$g}=$F[-1] } END { print $kv{$_} for(keys %kv) } ' file
```

with the given inputs in cara.txt file, the output is

```
$ perl -F, -lane ' ($g=$F[3])=~s/(^\S+).*/$1/; if( $mx{$g}<$F[-1]) 
       { $kv{$g}=$_;$mx{$g}=$F[-1] } END { print $kv{$_} for(keys %kv) }  ' cara.txt
AB179736.1.1725,AB179736.1.1725,278986,Pterocorys zancleus,0,1763
AB179735.1.1711,AB179735.1.1711,278983,Eucyrtidium hexagonatum,0,1600
AB120309.1.1800,AB120309.1.1800,4442,Camellia sinensis,0,1700
AB120002.1.1725,AB120002.1.1725,244961,Gyrodinium fusiforme,0,1800
AB181890.1.1709,AB181890.1.1709,281610,Protoperidinium denticulatum,0,1800

$
```

Answer (score -1):

Not fancy but gets the job done

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my @data = `cat /var/tmp/test.in`;

my %genuses = ();


foreach my $line ( @data ) {
  chomp($line);
  my @splitline = split(',', $line);
  my $genus = $splitline[3];
  my $num = $splitline[5];
  my ( $name, $extra ) = split(' ', $genus);
  if ( exists $genuses{$name}->{'num'} ) {
    if ( $genuses{$name}->{'num'} < $num ) {
      $genuses{$name}->{'num'} = $num;
      $genuses{$name}->{'line'} = $line;
    }
    else {
        next;
    }
  }
  else {
    $genuses{$name}->{'num'} = $num;
    $genuses{$name}->{'line'} = $line;
 }
}

foreach my $genus ( %genuses ) {
  print "$genuses{$genus}->{'line'}";
  print "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
[root@localhost tmp]# ./test.pl
AB179736.1.1725,AB179736.1.1725,278986,Pterocorys zancleus,0,1763
AB179735.1.1711,AB179735.1.1711,278983,Eucyrtidium hexagonatum,0,1600
AB120309.1.1800,AB120309.1.1800,4442,Camellia sinensis,0,1700
AB120002.1.1725,AB120002.1.1725,244961,Gyrodinium fusiforme,0,1800
AB181890.1.1709,AB181890.1.1709,281610,Protoperidinium denticulatum,0,1800
```

Don't see an obvious method that you are sorting your output by

Comment: Virtually identical to @choroba's answer, down to needlessly only handling a subset of CSV.